# Port MFC application to Linux using dot net core

Tags: linux, mfc, exe

I have an application written in MFC. Original problem is that I want to run this application in linux. I tried docker, it did not work. I tried wine, it did not work either. I came across dot net core and read that it can work both on windows and linux, so I can run my application in linux and windows. I tried to find if MFC application can be ported to dot net core or not, I could not find it.

Can anyone please suggest me if you have an answer to this question or a better solution to my problem?

Comment: No, MFC and .NET are too different for easy porting. But Wine should have worked.

Comment: I think the app is using some hardcoded destination so I am getting an error from wine that destination does not exist or someting

Comment: If you're talking about porting then you obviously have access to the source. Just change the part that accesses the file.

Comment: I can try that for sure

Comment: MFC is Windows-only. There is no way to port it to a different platform. You either have to rewrite a substantial part of the application, or run it in a virtualized Windows environment. .NET Core is a different execution environment. 'Porting' an MFC application to .NET Core is essentially a rewrite as well.

Comment: [DO NOT REWRITE SOFTWARE FROM SCRATCH!](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: Yes, it should work with wine. What didn't work with wine? Maybe you should post another question addressing this specific problem.